# Installing Ruby using rbenv on Ubuntu 14.04 virtualbox hangs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

I'm trying to get the Ruby on Rails running on `Ubuntu 14.04`. The Ubuntu is installed on VirtualBox. 
I'm following https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

When I run the command

```
rbenv install 2.1.2
```

Ruby keeps installing forever. I waited for more than 1 hour.

This is how the command-line looks:

```
rbenv install 2.1.2Downloading ruby-2.1.2.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/f22a6447811a81f3c808d1c2a5ce3b5f5f0955c68c9a749182feb425589e6635
Installing ruby-2.1.2...
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Same version of Ubuntu with the same version of Ruby. It just hangs after it is says `Installing ruby-2.1.2...`. I am using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesDullaghan/5941259) to setup the server and am experiencing the problem using rbenv instead of RVM.

Answer (score 43):

I thought the installation where frozen in the same point, but it just takes a long time to complete (1 hour and still running).
To see the installation progress add the verbose modifier to the command:

```
~$rbenv install --verbose 2.1.2
```

Note: I followed the [Deploy Ruby on Rails](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04) instructions for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that worked for me.

After about 20 minutes of it hanging this error popped up (some of the details cut out):

```
BUILD FAILED
(some extra details...)
The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

I then found and followed the answer in [this blog post](http://bullstools.blogspot.com/2013/05/install-ruby2.0-rails4.0-ubuntu12.04.html). It directs you to enter this command on the command line `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. After installing libssl-dev (extra details about it in the blog post) I was able to successfully install Ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: I gave up on rbenv and started using rvm. It worked like a breeze. So Im not sure if that was the problem

Comment: Might as well check this ruby-build ticket for more information: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/526

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here running `rbenv install 2.1.9`, it took 5-6 minutes to finish.